# Nodejs: can't get /

Tags: html, node.js, express, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to write a simple web page. It's based on 2 html and a index.js. I'm using nodejs and express for routing. When I launch with

> node index.js

it seems to work fine, until I get to the browser and go to

> localhost:8080/

then the browser tells me

> cannot get /

No error is displayed in the terminal nor in the console of both Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the code:

**index.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"main.html");
});

app.get("/choice/:choice/travel/:travel/name/:name", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("result.html", {
        choice : req.params.choice,
        travel : req.params.travel,
        name : req.params.name
    });
});

express().listen((process.env.PORT || 8080), function(){
    console.log("Server running at: "+(process.env.PORT || 8080));
});
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Survey Norway</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Survey Norway</h1>
<p>The survey is anonymous unless you insert your name<p>
<h2>Would you come to Norway this summer?</h2>
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" onclick="showMore()">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0" onclick="hide()">No
</form>
<div id="mytext" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Which one would you choose?</h2>
    <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="travel" value="1">Rent a car and travel Europe<br>
        <input type="radio" name="travel" value="2">Fly. <br>
        <input type="radio" name="travel" value="0">Doesn't matter.
    </form>
</div>
<p>If you want insert yor name here:.</p>
<input type="text" name="name">
<center>
    <button onclick="send_()">Send</button>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMore (){
        document.getElementById("mytext").style.display="block";
    }
    function hide (){
        document.getElementById("mytext").style.display="none";
    }
    function send_(){
        var choice=document.querySelector('input[name = "choice"]:checked').value;
        var viaggio=0; 
        if (choice==1){
            viaggio=document.querySelector('input[name = "travel"]:checked').value;
        }
        var nome=document.querySelector('input[name = "name"]').value;
        console.log("choice: "+choice+"\ntravel: "+travel+"\nname: "+name);
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
express().listen(...)
```

to this:

```
app.listen(...)
```

You were making a new express instance and listening with that one and that's a different instance than the one you put your routes on.  So, the server you actually created and started had no routes defined on it.

Comment: Wow that was so easy.. I've lost 1 hour of my life for nothing. Thank you very much!!!